# Implementing my own tree Iterator in Java

Tags: java, data-structures, tree, iterator, inorder

I as trying to implement the Iterator interface for tree traversal. I am getting the following error."Incompatible types at for(Integer node : tr )" and "treeIterator.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations." I am unable to fix this error. Can someone point out the problem.

```
//class to implement the Iterator interace.
class InorderItr implements Iterator {



    public InorderItr(Node root) {
       st = new Stack<Node>();
       this.root = root;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        //has Next
    }

    @Override
    public Integer next(){
          //next node
    }

    @Override 
    public void remove(){
        throw new java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException("Remove not supported.");
    }
}

//This class just makes sure that we use the foreach loop.
class InorderTreeIterator implements Iterable {

    Node root = null;

    public InorderTreeIterator(Node root){
        this.root = root;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<Integer> iterator(){
        try{
            return new InorderItr(this.root);
        } catch(UnsupportedOperationException e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
    }
}


class treeIterator {

    public static void main(String arg[]){
        treeIterator obj = new treeIterator();
        //create tree.
        InorderTreeIterator tr = new InorderTreeIterator(obj.root);
        for(Integer node : tr ){
            System.out.println(node);
        }
    }
}
```

PS: This is my first try at implementing iterator interface. If there are any standard practices that I am not following please point out.

Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Iterable` is a [generic](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html) interface. That means, unless you give it a type parameter, it will be a raw type, and the underlying data will be treated as `Object`.

Change this:

```
class InorderItr implements Iterator
class InorderTreeIterator implements Iterable
```

to the following:

```
class InorderItr implements Iterator<Integer>
class InorderTreeIterator implements Iterable<Integer>
```

This way, it is no longer a raw type (and that get rids of the warnings of unchecked and unsafe operations the compiler gives you currently), and it tells the compiler that the `Iterator` will have its underlying data type be `Integer` (since the type parameter in the `Iterator` interface is its underlying data type), so the type matches.

Comment: Thanks a lot....Solved my problem..now there seems to be logical error while doing inorder...Now I will look into it .. Thanks!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Iterator is a generic type. If you use the raw `Iterator` type, the Iterator returns Object, and the loop should be

```
for (Object node : tr)
```

You should instead use a type-safe generic `Iterator<Integer>`:

```
class InorderItr implements Iterator<Integer> {

...

class InorderTreeIterator implements Iterable<Integer> {
```

Also, choose better names for your classes. `InorderItr` should be `InOrderIterator`. And `InorderTreeIterator` should be `InorderTreeIterable`. Don't name "Iterator" what is not an Iterator. Start class names with upper-case letters, and method names with lower-case letters.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Java 5 or later: Iterator is actually declared as Iterator, where "E" represents the class returned by next() on the Iterator.  I think what you want is

```
InOrderIterator implements Iterator<Node>
```

and next() should be declared as

```
public Node next()
```

I do not understand why you have Integer in your code; you are clearly attempting to iterate over a tree of Node.

Comment: Will I am returning the int part of the node not the node itself..that it why I choose to use Integer..

Comment: Iterator normally proceeds through a collection of a given class; you used to have Node defined, but now you don't. The definition you had showed Node as having state to be a node in a binary tree. I assumed you were iterating through nodes in the tree, which would be a normal use of an iterator.  It is less normal to use an iterator on a collection of one class and have it return a different class.  You wanted to know about practices that were not standard, so here is one.

Answer (score 0):

In space (kinda) implementation in C++

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
struct node
{
    node *left;
    node *right;
    node *parent;
    int data;
} ;

class bst
{
public:
    node *root;
    node *currNode;

    bst()
    {
        root=NULL;
        currNode = NULL;
    }
    int isempty() 
    {
        return(root==NULL);
    }
    void insert(int item);
    void inordertrav();
    void inorder(node *);
    int next();
    node *nextNode(node *root);
    void bft();
};
void bst::insert(int item)
{
    node *p=new node;
    node *parent;
    p->data=item;
    p->left=NULL;
    p->right=NULL;
    p->parent = NULL;
    parent=NULL;
    if(isempty())
        root=p;
    else
    {
        node *ptr;
        ptr = root;
        while(ptr!=NULL)
        {
            parent = ptr;
            if(item > ptr->data)        
                ptr = ptr->right;
            else
                ptr=ptr->left;
        }   
        if(item < parent->data)
        {
            parent->left = p;
        }
        else
            parent->right = p;
        p->parent = parent;
    }
}
void bst::inordertrav()
{
    inorder(root);
}
void bst::inorder(node *ptr)
{
    if(ptr!=NULL)
    {
        inorder(ptr->left);
        cout<<"  "<<ptr->data<<"     ";
        inorder(ptr->right);
    }
}

int bst::next()
{
// If currNode is NULL and find the left most node using a while loop.
    if (currNode == NULL)
    {
        cout << "First node data" << endl;
        node *tmp = root;
        while (tmp->left != NULL)
            tmp = tmp->left;

        currNode = tmp;
        return currNode->data;
    }
    cout << endl << "Current Node is - " << currNode->data << endl;
    if (currNode->right)
    {
        node *tmp = currNode->right;
        while (tmp->left) // find the leftmost node for this right subtree in recursive way without recursion
            tmp = tmp->left;
        currNode = tmp;
        return currNode->data;
    }

    if (! currNode->right) // currNode does not have right child
    {
        if ( currNode->parent->left && currNode->data == currNode->parent->left->data) // CurrNode is the left child
        {
            currNode = currNode->parent;
            return currNode->data;
        }
        if (currNode->parent->right && currNode->data == currNode->parent->right->data) //CurrNode is the right child of the parent
        {
            //If the parent of the currNode (which is right child) is also a right child
            //then this currNode is actually a leaf node and it nothing should be returned.
            if (currNode->parent->parent->right && 
                    currNode->parent->parent->right->data == currNode->parent->data)
            {
                cout << "The tree has been travered fully";
                return -1;
            }
            currNode = currNode->parent->parent;
            return currNode->data;
        }
    }
}


int main()
{
    bst b;
    b.insert(52);
    b.insert(25);
    b.insert(50);
    b.insert(40);
    b.insert(45);
    b.insert(20);
    b.insert(75);
    b.insert(65);
    b.insert(78);
    b.insert(23);
    b.insert(15);

    cout << "---- In order traversal using iterator -----" << endl;
    int i;
    do
    {
        i = b.next();   
        cout << " " << i << " ";
    }while (i != -1);
    cout << endl;
    cout<<endl;
}
```

Comment: This uses only next() function and moves to the next in-order element.